# Как создавать последовательные анимации чтобы это было слаженно

Tags: java, javafx, анимация

UPD: Мне подойдет любой вариант кода благодаря которому я смогу создать необходимую анимацию. Не обязательно отталкиваться от моих вариантов.

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию где в окошке крутятся изображения и никак не получается сделать её процесс плавным.
По стандарту в панели имеется 5 изображений (пятое справа, за пределами экрана).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По ходу анимации планировалось что все элементы сдвигаются влево на -150 (размер изображений) и по окончанию данного `Timeline` активируется `onFinished` метод, который удаляет с панели первое имеющиеся изображение и добавляет новое, а затем создает новый таймлайн по тому же принципу и с тем же ивентом по окончанию.

Но проблема в том что после первой итерации таймлайна добавленные картинки уже появляются на расстоянии в те же 150 width. И в дополнение происходит небольшой визуальный рывок всех изображений.
Я понимаю что это происходит почти наверняка из-за действия удаления первого изображения, но и другого варианта придумать не могу не засоряя панель сотней картинок.

Вот как это начинает выглядеть дальше:
[image]

Как мне исправить мой код чтобы в анимации изображения шли без рывком и увеличения пространства между ними? Если есть вариант реализовать мою идею в виде одной анимации то этот вариант тоже подошел бы.

Код отвечающий за создание изначальной анимации по нажатию кнопки:

```
Timeline mainTimeline = new Timeline();
for(int f = 0; f<5; f++) {
    if(f==0) {
        KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(DURATION,evt -> {
            heroSpin.getChildren().remove(0);
            heroSpin.getChildren().add(allWorkingIM.get(ImageViewCount));
            ImageViewCount++;
            makeNewTimeLine(allWorkingIM);}
        , new KeyValue(heroSpin.getChildren().get(f).translateXProperty(), STEP));  
        mainTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
    } else {
    KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(DURATION, new KeyValue(heroSpin.getChildren().get(f).translateXProperty(), STEP));
        mainTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
}}
mainTimeline.setCycleCount(1);
mainTimeline.play();
```

И практически такой же код метода вызываемого по окончанию этой анимации:

```
Timeline newTimeline = new Timeline();
for(int g = 0; g<5; g++) {   
    if(g==0) {
        KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(DURATION,evt -> {
        heroSpin.getChildren().remove(0);
        heroSpin.getChildren().add(iva.get(ImageViewCount));
        ImageViewCount++;
        makeNewTimeLine(iva);}
        , new KeyValue(heroSpin.getChildren().get(g).translateXProperty(),  heroSpin.getChildren().get(g).getTranslateX()-150,Interpolator.LINEAR));
        newTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
    } else {
    KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(DURATION, new KeyValue(heroSpin.getChildren().get(g).translateXProperty(), heroSpin.getChildren().get(g).getTranslateX()-150,Interpolator.LINEAR));
    newTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
    }
}
newTimeline.setCycleCount(1);
newTimeline.play();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535333/javafx-smooth-animation Хорошое обьяснение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и предполагал решение оказалось проще изначального варианта.
Перебирая варианты немного изменил подход и вместо при начале анимации стал добавлять в контейнер сразу все `ImageView`, а вместо удаления изображений ушедших из зоны видимости просто позволил им собираться на финальной точке.
Возможно при работе с огромными количествами изображений это будет иметь побочные эффекты, но в моем случае все стало прогружаться даже быстрее и решило проблему с пустотами между изображениями.

Вот так это выглядит у меня в итоге:

- Первым шагом добавляю все `ImageView` в контейнер
- Затем создаю `Timeline` в котором для каждого элемента контейнера создаю `FrameKey`  с соответственно увеличивающимся числом продолжительности и изменения координаты `X` для каждого следующего изображения:

  ```
   Timeline mainTimeline = new Timeline();
   for(int c = 0, translateNum = -256, durationNum = 1000; c < heroSpin.getChildren().size(); c++, translateNum = translateNum-256,durationNum= durationNum+1000) {
       KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(new Duration(durationNum),  new KeyValue(heroSpin.getChildren().get(c).translateXProperty(), translateNum));    
       mainTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
   }
   mainTimeline.setCycleCount(1);
   mainTimeline.play();
  ```

В результате получаю равномерную анимацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]